# Suppress one x-axis, keep the other with ggtree and geom_facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtree, x-axis

I'm trying to remove the x-axis from one plot (the tree on the left should have no x-axis labels, ticks, line, etc.), while keeping the x-axis on the plot on the right (0-60, ticks, label: "Number of G's"). I've unsuccessfully searched through nearly all ggtree blogs, ggtree github, ggplot2 help, ggtree help, etc.

The picture shows what my plot looks like without any tip labels or legend: [image: my plot without tip labels or legend]

Someone else is looking for an answer to the same question here: https://groups.google.com/g/bioc-ggtree/c/CPb1C955PHo.

```
p <- ggtree(phylo) +  geom_tiplab(offset=1, hjust=.8, size=2.5) + 
     geom_facet(panel="GS", data=res3, geom = ggstance::geom_barh, 
        mapping = aes(x= Freq,group= as.factor(res3$CG),fill= GS), 
        color='grey90', lwd=.3, stat="identity") +
    theme_tree2(legend.position=c(.85, .45)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,5,10,15,20,30,40,50,60)) + 
    theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank()) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "GS", values=c("#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#E69F00", "#F0E442", "#999999", "#009E73"))

p
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
phylop <- ggtree(phylo) +  geom_tiplab(offset=0.1, hjust=0, size=2.5) + xlim_tree(5.3)
bars <-  ggplot(res3, aes(y= Freq,x= as.factor(CG))) + geom_col(aes(fill=GS)) + 
    # geom_text(aes(label=CG, y= Freq)) +
    coord_flip() + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,30,40,50,60)) + 
    theme_tree2() + theme(legend.position=c(.70, .65)) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "GS", values=c("#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#E69F00", "#F0E442", "#999999", "#009E73"))

cowplot::plot_grid(phylop, bars, ncol=2)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using cowplot?